# Can I Parse and/or include "And" in my SQL Statement for a full text index?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, full-text-search

So I have a query that looks at a full text index like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 q  
    INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(Table1,TableField, @Keywords) search 
    ON q.Key = search.[KEY]
```

Now `@Keywords` can be either a Word (For example: Moo), a Phrase (e.g. Chocolate Milk) or a Search String (e.g. Chocolate AND Milk).  However I get an error when it's a phrase (Chocolate Milk) evidently it's expecting a single word or search string.

*What's the easiest way to build the intelligence in to understand a phrase vs. a Search string?*